# Non-vegan building materials?

Tags: veganism

Are there any building materials considered non-vegan, especially in the context of constructing apartment buildings?

Comment: Do you have any specific concerns?

Comment: Well, there's a patent for the ["Use of blood in the cement, mortar and concrete industry for obtaining a lightened material"](https://www.google.com/patents/US4203674). Above that, it is conceivable that there is non-vegan insulation, paint, glue...

Comment: I believe wooden beams used to be painted in ox blood for fire protection. Animal glue, wouldn't be used these days anymore, except maybe for a historic restauration.

Answer (score 1):

Rammed Earth may be non-vegan as it has traditionally used [blood as a binding material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rammed_earth#Composition_and_use).

But now we come to a thorny question for vegans.  Since concrete is made from cement which is made from limestone which *often* comes from caves where bats lose their home, will you use concrete?  Animals may have suffered in its production.

Comment: It's not thorny if you don't require vegans do go further down the rabbit hole than anyone else.